# Get JQuery script to run when field is tabbed to

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, user-experience, contact-form

I have a field that runs a JQuery script when it is clicked. This is a field in a form.

However, I need the scrip to run if the field is tabbed to, as some users prefer to do.

This is currently my script

```
Query(function($){
$('span.website input.url').one("click", function() {
$('span.website input.url').val($('span.website input.url').val() + 'http://');})
});
```

How can I alter this to work the field is tabbed to?

Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to bind to `focus` instead of `click`

```
$('span.website input.url').one("click"...
```

to

```
$('span.website input.url').one("focus"...
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use jQuery's Focus:

http://api.jquery.com/focus/

Answer (score 0):

The code to assign the function to both click and focus, or "tabbing" events could be like this one

```
Query(function($){
    function aName () {
        $('span.website input.url').val($('span.website input.url').val() + 'http://');
    }
    $('span.website input.url').one("click", aName);
    $('span.website input.url').one("focus", aName);
});
```

Let me know if it works fine for you.